# What's the difference in meaning between the words טעם and עילה?

Tags: words, translation

In the introduction to Chovos Halevavos, R. Bachya (as translated by R. Yehuda Ibn Tibbon) writes:

> מצות השמע שאין השכל מחייב בהם ולא דוחה אותם כאיסור בשר בחלב ושעטנז
> וכלאים והדומה להם ממה שנעלמה ממנו **עילת** איסורם **ועילת** חיוב ממה
> שנתחייבנו מהן.

He seems to be referring to reasons for the mitzvos, but **עילה** is used here as opposed to **טעם**.

Assuming

1. טעם and עילה have different meanings
2. The translator chose עילה
   over טעם deliberately

What did he intend to convey here by the usage
of the word עילה.

*Or more simply, what, in general, is the difference between the meaning of the words עילה and טעם?*

Comment: One seems to be translated as “rationale” or something close to that while the other is “reason”. Rationale would represent a more calculated reason. No source, just a hunch

Comment: ChatGPT agrees with @Chatzkel: https://chat.openai.com/share/03d3c61c-27df-4ee5-a4a6-7baa3f6acd78

Comment: Firstly, @Chatzkel- can you elaborate on what you mean by this distinction. I don't fully understand it

Comment: @shmosel I absolutely LOVE the chat GPT answer, and I think it's so cool! I'm biased, because that's exactly what I told my chavrusa when we learning it but I couldn't full express it. Can you post it as an amswer? If not, I will... Thank you!!!

Comment: It's officially banned on stack exchange. Not sure what the policy is if it's explicitly sourced. Maybe one of the mods can comment.

Answer (score 0):

עילה means "cause", and טעם means "reason". So while we can understand many "reasons" for various mitzvos, we cannot understand the ultimate true reason, as that requires seeing things from G-d's perspective, which is above us.